# FireFox transform and transition not working

Tags: css, firefox

So, this is my CSS:

```
img.buttonImg {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
}

img.buttonImg:hover { 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
```

Yet no animation seems to happen, the image isn't rotating at all on FireFox, but on other browsers it does.

Comment: Works in the latest version of FF for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/5YrXb/

Comment: It worked for me to, strange, look at this:  http://www.xero-accounts.tk/  the icons on the button's shout rotate, and I copied that CSS from the style sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem - demonstrated by [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/yAgQ7/3/).

The transition doesn't work when hovering over the `img` element because of the fact that it is within a `button` element. I assume this is a rendering issue, as this *only* seems to be the case for **FF**. It works fine in Chrome and other modern browsers.

As for a solution, removing the `img` element from the `button` will obviously solve the problem.

Alternatively, you could add the rotation transition effect when hovering over the `button` as opposed to the child `img` element. [**Updated example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/yAgQ7/6/) - it works in FF.

```
button.t:hover img { 
    transform: rotate(360deg);
   /* other vendors.. */
}
```

Both solutions work; however, I don't even know if it is valid to have an `img` element within a `button` element. This is probably the reason for the rendering bug; if it even is a bug.

Comment: The problem is that I need the button, but I don't want the whole button to rotate. I also need the button effects.  Any other solutions?