# animation working on chrome but not on mozilla and safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, webkit, mozilla

i have this code for a button so it will grow when i hover over it

```
.btn_pr {
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-transition-duration: 700ms;
-moz-transform: scale(1,1);
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
-moz-transition-duration: 700ms;
}

.btn_pr:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.15,1.15);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-transition-duration: 700ms;
-moz-transform: scale(1.15,1.15);
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
-moz-transition-duration: 700ms;
}
```

it works perfectly on chrome, but it doesn't do anything on mozilla and safari, can someone help me with what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You need the non-vendor-prefixed versions of these properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```css
.btn_pr {
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition:all 700ms ease;
}
.btn_pr:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.15);
            transform:scale(1.15);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn_pr">Test button</button>
```

Here's a fully prefixed version of the CSS above, created with Autoprefixer set to last 500 versions:

```
.btn_pr {
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
       -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-transition:all 700ms ease;
       -moz-transition:all 700ms ease;
         -o-transition:all 700ms ease;
            transition:all 700ms ease;
}
.btn_pr:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.15);
            -moz-transform:scale(1.15);
             -ms-transform:scale(1.15);
              -o-transform:scale(1.15);
         transform:scale(1.15);
}
```

Comment: nope, it works the same on chrome but still nothing on mozilla

Comment: Firefox (and Chrome) shouldn't need vendor prefixes.  Chrome dropped the prefixes as of version 35 according to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS3%20Transforms).  Are you running an up-to-date version of Firefox?  I edited my answer with a completely prefixed alternate version.

Comment: nope, still nothing on neither firefox nor safari, and yes, both are up to date

Comment: Perhaps it's a browser limitation.  Do both of [these squares spin](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/yAgQ7/3/) when you mouse over them?  [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732297/firefox-transform-and-transition-not-working)

Comment: on safari and chrome both of them spin, on firefox only the right one

Comment: That confirms it's a browser issue then, unfortunately.  Try making the tag not a `button`, but an anchor or something: http://jsfiddle.net/waqrwejf/1/ and apply your old styles accordingly.